# Oreo 8.0,8.1:IndexOutOfBoundsException for SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan

Tags: android, spannablestringbuilder

Following error found on Oreo version 8.0 and 8.1, but working fine on other Android versions.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange (SpannableStringBuilder.java:1314)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan (SpannableStringBuilder.java:680)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan (SpannableStringBuilder.java:672)
  at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.setText (AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:2476)
  at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal (TextView.java:10371)
  at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo (View.java:7345)
  at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal (View.java:7304)
  at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo (View.java:7289)
  at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode (AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1147)
  at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode (AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1170)
  at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode (AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1170)
  at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode (AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1170)
  at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode (AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1170)
  at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos (AccessibilityInteractionController.java:972)
  at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread (AccessibilityInteractionController.java:336)
  at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.-wrap1 (Unknown Source)
  at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage (AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1324)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6494)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Please help how to resolve it.

Comment: share your code.

Comment: i have same error